# Getting a fractional number with scanf

Tags: c, io, c99

In the following if I write `scanf` with `%d /%d"` (with a space) then I can input a fraction seperated by spaces.

**For example:** The input can be `5/7` or `5 /7` or  `5 / 7` (with spaces anywhere).

How does scanf in the code below read spaces between numbers that way but yet it is has only one space between `%d /%d"`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i, j;
   scanf("%d /%d", &i, &j);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A space (or newline, tab) in a `scanf` format consumes a maximal sequence (maybe empty) of adjacent whitespace characters. So `"%d /%d"` allows whitespace between numerator and slash, but doesn't require it. The `%d` format skips leading whitespace, so there can also be whitespace between the slash and the denominator.

Comment: Ah, so `%d` skips any whitespace before reading anything in the first place. It makes sense now. I'll accept it if this were an answer.

Comment: You can accept jedwards' or AndreyT's answer, that also covers everything, and I don't want to duplicate it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all input format specifiers in `scanf` will automatically skip all whitespace before reading the actual data. E.g. the `%d` format specifier in `scanf` actually means `<skip spaces> <read int>`.

That means that if we used `%d/%d` format for reading fractions, it would stand for

```
<skip spaces> <read int> <require /> <skip spaces> <read int>
```

In this sequence we have everything necessary, except we don't allow/skip spaces before the `/`. To fix that we have to add an explicit request to skip spaces before `/`, which in `scanf` format string is expressed by a space character. Adding a space character before `/` produces `%d /%d` format string, which stands for

```
<skip spaces> <read int> <skip spaces> <require /> <skip spaces> <read int>
```

This is exactly what we need and that is exactly what you have in your code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on here.

The first is that the `%d` specifier will "trim" whitespace leading up to a decimal number, so that is why `(space)4` is parsed the same as simply `4` (without the leading space).

The second is that if you place whitespace in the format string, it will "eat" any number of whitespace characters (including zero).

> Whitespace character: the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).

[Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

So your space in the format string before the `/` will allow you to match strings both with separating whitespace (eg `4 /x`) and without (eg `4/x`).